# Template literal in MongoDB query with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a query with template literals, like this:

```js
router.post('/login', middleware.isLoggedOut, function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
      else
      {
        console.log(req.body);
        var y=0;
        User.findOne({'username': req.body.username, `privileges.${y}.region`: req.body.regiuni}, function(err, usr)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else
            {
                if(usr === null)
                {
                    console.log("no usr");
                }
                else
                {
                    req.logIn(usr, function(err)
                {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
                })
                }    
            }
        })
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

I can't really get how I should use the template literal here "`privileges.${y}.region`" because right now it doesn't work. I get "unexpected template string" in the node shell, but vs code also seem not to interpret it as I want because it colors the code like the template literal is this:

```js
: req.body.regiuni}, function(err, usr)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else
            {
                if(usr === null)
                {
                    console.log("no usr");
                }
                else
                {
                    req.logIn(usr, function(err)
                {
                    if(err)
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
                })
                }    
            }
        })
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  });

module.exports = router;
```

[image: click]
Why does it happen and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

You need to have it inside of brackets, like

```
[`privileges.${y}.region`]: req.body.regiuni
```

It's an object, think about the way you'd access it.

Would you do

```
obj.`privileges.${y}.region`?
```

Nop, you'd use brackets

```
obj.[`privileges.${y}.region`]
```

Comment: I don't really get why. Why is that an object? I see it as 'username'

Comment: @AndreiDaniel `User.findOne` takes an object as a parameter. You can just send the object, or you could do `var obj = {{'username': req.body.username}`, and do `User.findOne(obj)`